# 500 Error: Custom JSP page with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, error-handling

I want to provide users a custom JSP page to deal with the error 500.

So far i tried the normal configuration in `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
    <description>Uncaught exception</description>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Which is not working.

And I also i tried this configuration by Google App Engine:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses

```
<static-error-handlers>
    <handler file="/error500.jsp" />
</static-error-handlers>
```

I don't know which ones to use and I didn't manage to make any working.

Comment: Please check this in firefox. If in firefox it works then you can change settings in IE using:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defined the error500.jsp as a servlet with an url pattern and it's now working with the config in web.xml.

But a direct access to error500.jsp get me a 404.
So there is a problem but there is a work around.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>error500</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/error500.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>error500</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error500</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error500</location>
</error-page>
```